# Getting an error that says TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting in Python when decomposing time series

Tags: python, time-series

Working on a time series model in python and am getting an error that says : TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting in Python when I run the following code. My data looks something like this:

I've searched and found an article that there's an error on a string value, however, I don't have any string datatypes in my data. Day is a INT and Revenue is a float64. Since the error appears to be on seasonal_decompose, the only thing I can think of is that freq="D" is causing the error. But everything I've found online says that that is correct. Any ideas?

```
Day     Revenue (in millions)
1        1.234
2        1.3455
3        2.432
```

```
df_log.reset_index(inplace=True)
df_log['Day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Day'])
df_log = df_log.set_index('Day')

decomposition = seasonal_decompose(df_log, freq ="D")
model = ARIMA(df_log, order=(2,1,2))
results = model.fit(disp=-1)
plt.plot(df_log_shift)
plt.plot(results.fittedvalues, color='red')
```

Here's the full error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-15c3724319d3> in <module>
      3 df_log = df_log.set_index('Day')
      4 
----> 5 decomposition = seasonal_decompose(df_log, freq ="D")
      6 model = ARIMA(df_log, order=(2,1,2))
      7 results = model.fit(disp=-1)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/seasonal.py in seasonal_decompose(x, model, filt, freq, two_sided, extrapolate_trend)
    130 
    131     if filt is None:
--> 132         if freq % 2 == 0:  # split weights at ends
    133             filt = np.array([.5] + [1] * (freq - 1) + [.5]) / freq
    134         else:
```

Comment: `seasonal_decompose()` expects `freq` to be a number, not a string. Why are you passing `freq = "D"`?

Comment: I don't see anything in https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.seasonal_decompose.html that suggests that `freq="D"` is valid. Although I think it's only supposed to be used when `extrapolate_trend="freq"`

Comment: I used https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html and little ways down and saw it. I believe I tried freq=1 originally. I'll try it again to make sure, Thanks.

Comment: I can't find `seasonal_decompose` in that documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
 The seasonal decompose contains trend, seasonal and residual graphs.  The dataframe index needs to be a date time index type

import statsmodels.api as sm
 from pylab import rcParams

 rcParams['figure.figsize']=11,9
 decomposition=sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(
df['value'], model=’additive’, extrapolate_trend='freq', period=12 )
```

https://youtu.be/6u6bM3s5qsM

Comment: While this might (or might not, I don't know) answer the question, it's really hard to know what you're saying without some explanation. Please add a few sentences explaining how this solves the problem.

Comment: Here is an explanation of the seasonal decompose components and types. https://youtu.be/pLHm4cvoZiY